# Display multiple products once we click on link on view page

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-view

we have to implement "shop the look" feature.

ex : if shirt is the main product , than shop the look is

```
shirt [product1] + matching jeans [product 2].
```

[image]

If we click on "shop the look" present in bottom left,  than it should display 2 products in right side with one original product.

[image]

How to achieve this as [here](http://www.jabong.com/Us_Polo_Assn-Light-Blue-Printed-Regular-Fit-Casual-Shirt-2080781.html?pos=3)

Comment: Your specific UX approach will dictate whether or not you can use out of the box. In the case of choosing sizes from the PDP itself, no you cannot do that in vanilla Magento 1. They want you to choose sizes from the corresponding PDP. In this case you will want to use a 3rd party module. I think that this question may be too broad and so I'll put it on hold for now until you clarify.

Comment: @philwinkle thanks for guiding me regarding selecting sizes. I edited the question, Right now i don't require selecting the size feature.

Comment: @philwinkle i updated question to make it simple. when you get free time, please check once.